# Apache Ignite compile ODBC driver errors

Tags: c++, makefile, ignite

I try to compile odbc driver but I have following errors:

I run following commands:

```
1. cd ./modules/platforms/cpp
2. libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoreconf
3. ./configure
4. make
```

Errors are:

```
error: 'ignite::odbc::ssl::OPENSSL_init_ssl' declared as an 'inline' variable
error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
error: variable or field 'OPENSSL_init_ssl' declared void
error: 'ignite::odbc::ssl::OPENSSL_init_ssl' cannot be used as a function
error: 'SSL_CTRL_OPTIONS' was not declared in this scope
```

My Ignite version is 2.5 downloaded by (on 01.03.2018):

```
git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/ignite
```

Please help me.

Comment: I assume that's your thread - http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/ODBC-driver-compile-error-td20313.html? Did the suggestions there helped you?

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed on Apache Ignite users mailing list: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/ODBC-driver-compile-error-td20313.html