# Apache Ignite v2.7: Can't build linux ODBC driver - inline variable compile error

Tags: c++, odbc, ignite

I'm trying to build the Apache Ignite ODBC driver for Linux within a Dockerfile for a .Net Core Webapi project, however I get errors when it tries to build the SSL cpp files.

I did find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047925/apache-ignite-campile-odbc-driver-errors), but I was unable to apply the [patch](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/file/t938/01.patch) mentioned in this [thread](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/ODBC-driver-compile-error-td20313.html). I believe it's because I'm on v2.7 and it was for v2.5.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /src
# Install pre-requisites for building and installing Ignite ODBC Driver
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc g++ make automake autotools-dev libtool m4 libssl-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get clean -y

# Download and unzip Ignite binary release
ADD ["http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/ignite/2.7.0/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip", "/src/"]
RUN unzip -q /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip
RUN rm /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin.zip

# Build Ignite ODBC Driver
ARG IGNITE_HOME=/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin
WORKDIR /src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp
RUN libtoolize
RUN aclocal
RUN autoheader
RUN automake --add-missing
RUN autoreconf
RUN ./configure --enable-odbc --disable-core --disable-node

RUN make
```

Here's the result from calling `make`:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp'
Making all in common
make[2]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common'
Making all in include
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common/include'
Making all in os/linux/include
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common/os/linux/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common/os/linux/include'
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common'
  CXX      os/linux/src/common/concurrent_os.lo
  CXX      os/linux/src/common/platform_utils.lo
  CXX      os/linux/src/common/dynamic_load_os.lo
  CXX      src/common/big_integer.lo
  CXX      src/common/bits.lo
  CXX      src/common/concurrent.lo
  CXX      src/common/decimal.lo
  CXX      src/common/utils.lo
  CXX      src/date.lo
  CXX      src/ignite_error.lo
  CXX      src/guid.lo
  CXX      src/timestamp.lo
  CXX      src/time.lo
  CXXLD    libignite-common.la
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/common'
Making all in binary
make[2]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/binary'
Making all in include
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/binary/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/binary/include'
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/binary'
  CXX      src/binary/binary_containers.lo
  CXX      src/binary/binary_raw_writer.lo
  CXX      src/binary/binary_writer.lo
  CXX      src/binary/binary_reader.lo
  CXX      src/binary/binary_type.lo
  CXX      src/binary/binary_raw_reader.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_type_manager.lo
src/impl/binary/binary_type_manager.cpp: In member function 'ignite::common::concurrent::SharedPointer<ignite::impl::binary::BinaryTypeHandler> ignite::impl::binary::BinaryTypeManager::GetHandler(const string&, int32_t)':
src/impl/binary/binary_type_manager.cpp:60:43: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
                     for (int32_t i = 0; i < pending->size(); ++i)
                                         ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/impl/binary/binary_type_manager.cpp: In member function 'ignite::impl::binary::SPSnap ignite::impl::binary::BinaryTypeManager::GetMeta(int32_t)':
src/impl/binary/binary_type_manager.cpp:170:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
                 for (int32_t i = 0; i < pending->size(); ++i)
                                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_type_impl.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_utils.lo
src/impl/binary/binary_utils.cpp: In static member function 'static int32_t ignite::impl::binary::BinaryUtils::GetDataHashCode(const void*, size_t)':
src/impl/binary/binary_utils.cpp:92:39: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
                     for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                                     ~~^~~~~~
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_reader_impl.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_type_handler.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_writer_impl.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_schema.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_type_snapshot.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_object_header.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_object_impl.lo
  CXX      src/impl/binary/binary_field_meta.lo
  CXX      src/impl/interop/interop_memory.lo
  CXX      src/impl/interop/interop_output_stream.lo
  CXX      src/impl/interop/interop_input_stream.lo
  CXXLD    libignite-binary.la
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/binary'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/binary'
Making all in odbc
make[2]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc'
Making all in include
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc/include'
make[3]: Entering directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc'
  CXX      os/linux/src/system/tcp_socket_client.lo
  CXX      src/app/application_data_buffer.lo
  CXX      src/app/parameter.lo
src/app/parameter.cpp: In member function 'bool ignite::odbc::app::Parameter::IsDataReady() const':
src/app/parameter.cpp:235:42: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
                        storedData.size() == buffer.GetDataAtExecSize();
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CXX      src/app/parameter_set.lo
  CXX      src/common_types.lo
  CXX      src/config/config_tools.lo
  CXX      src/config/configuration.lo
  CXX      src/config/connection_info.lo
  CXX      src/config/connection_string_parser.lo
  CXX      src/connection.lo
  CXX      src/cursor.lo
  CXX      src/diagnostic/diagnosable_adapter.lo
  CXX      src/diagnostic/diagnostic_record.lo
  CXX      src/diagnostic/diagnostic_record_storage.lo
  CXX      src/environment.lo
  CXX      src/meta/column_meta.lo
  CXX      src/meta/table_meta.lo
  CXX      src/odbc.lo
  CXX      src/entry_points.lo
  CXX      src/dsn_config.lo
  CXX      src/query/column_metadata_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/data_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/batch_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/foreign_keys_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/primary_keys_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/table_metadata_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/type_info_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/special_columns_query.lo
  CXX      src/query/streaming_query.lo
  CXX      src/ssl/ssl_gateway.lo
  CXX      src/ssl/secure_socket_client.lo
In file included from ./include/ignite/odbc/ssl/ssl_bindings.h:21:0,
                 from src/ssl/secure_socket_client.cpp:25:
./include/ignite/odbc/ssl/ssl_bindings.h:133:24: error: 'ignite::odbc::ssl::OPENSSL_init_ssl' declared as an 'inline' variable
             inline int SSL_library_init()
                        ^
./include/ignite/odbc/ssl/ssl_bindings.h:133:24: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
             inline int SSL_library_init()
                        ^
In file included from src/ssl/secure_socket_client.cpp:25:0:
./include/ignite/odbc/ssl/ssl_bindings.h:134:13: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
             {
             ^
In file included from ./include/ignite/odbc/ssl/ssl_bindings.h:21:0,
                 from src/ssl/secure_socket_client.cpp:25:
./include/ignite/odbc/ssl/ssl_bindings.h:142:25: error: variable or field 'OPENSSL_init_ssl' declared void
             inline void SSL_load_error_strings()
                         ^
src/ssl/secure_socket_client.cpp: In static member function 'static void* ignite::odbc::ssl::SecureSocketClient::MakeContext(const string&, const string&, const string&, ignite::odbc::diagnostic::Diagnosable&)':
src/ssl/secure_socket_client.cpp:206:31: error: 'ignite::odbc::ssl::OPENSSL_init_ssl' cannot be used as a function
                         (void)SSL_library_init();
                               ^
src/ssl/secure_socket_client.cpp:208:25: error: 'ignite::odbc::ssl::OPENSSL_init_ssl' cannot be used as a function
                         SSL_load_error_strings();
                         ^
src/ssl/secure_socket_client.cpp:237:40: error: 'SSL_CTRL_OPTIONS' was not declared in this scope
                 ssl::SSL_CTX_ctrl(ctx, SSL_CTRL_OPTIONS, flags, NULL);
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Makefile:782: recipe for target 'src/ssl/secure_socket_client.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [src/ssl/secure_socket_client.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc'
Makefile:812: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp/odbc'
Makefile:423: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/src/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin/platforms/cpp'
Makefile:355: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**SOLUTION**: The issue was that I was using the wrong libssl-dev package. The latest at the time of writing this question was 1.1, whereas I needed 1.0. Changing `libssl-dev` to `libssl1.0-dev` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL do you have in your Docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build Apache Ignite 2.7 ODBC against libSSL 1.0 header files & library.

Uninstall OpenSSL 1.1 developer package, install OpenSSL 1.0 developer pachage.

Comment: Thank you! Changing libssl-dev to libssl1.0-dev fixed the issue for me.